# Binding a Generic List to a Dropdownlistfor in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a generic list method that returns a CategoryID and CategoryName.
I have spent enough time researching and cant seem to put it together. I very new at MVC.

**Here is my DropdownList Method in a repository. I get back the data... So far so good.**

```
public List<DropdownList> GetDDl()
{

return catDDL; 
}
```

**Here is my CONTROLLER CODE(attempt at it)**

```
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> liCat =
 userRepository.Getddl().Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
   Value = c.DropDownID.ToString(),
   Text = c.DropDownText
}
ViewBag.catItems = new SelecList(liCat,"Value","Text");
```

**Here is my VIEW**

```
@Html.Dropdownlist("catItems","Select Category)
```

Comment: I understand that you might be simplifying for the sake of posting on the site .. but for good design, don't create a repository method called GetDDl, call it GetCategories() or whatever makes sense and let it return a List<Category>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to avoid dynamic stuff like `ViewBag` and `ViewData`. Use strongly typed views.

ViewModel is just a POCO class which we will use to transfer data between your view and the action method. It will be specific to the view.

ex : if you want to create a view which creates a product. So create a viewmodel like this

```
public class Product
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories{ get; set; }
  public string SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
  //Other Properties as needed

}
```

now in your `GET` action method, you create an object of this view model and initialize the values and send to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new Product();
  vm.Categories=userRepository.Getddl().
               Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                    Value = c.DropDownID.ToString(),
                                    Text = c.DropDownText
                                 });                    
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now make your view strongly typed to our `Product` class and use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method.

```
@model PersonsProduct 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId, 
                       new SelectList(Model.Categories,"Value","Text"), "Select")
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

Now in your HttpPost , you can get the form values like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     //check model.SelectedCategoryId
     //save and redirect
  }
  //to do :reload the dropdown again.
  return view(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju.  Ill give a try and get right back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Should just be:

Controller:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> liCat = userRepository.Getddl().Select(c => new SelectListItem
{
   Value = c.DropDownID.ToString(),
   Text = c.DropDownText
}

ViewBag.catItems = liCat
```

View:

```
@Html.Dropdownlist("catItems", ViewBag.catItems)
```

Comment: Kabaros - I get the same issue I had with my code. The ID is coming back at zero when going thru the second Create Method attributed with HTTPOST. Any Idea why it might be zero. I tested it with creating a hardcoded list of Selectlist items and it works. I like MVC and I know I am new but the DDL is a real pain.