# MVC: Correct way to bind DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create a form to insert an Author. In that form, there will be a DropDownList for AuthorCategory. Both Author and AuthorCategory are model classes.

I created a ViewModel just for the relevant fields of creating an author, which have public properties of FullName, Email and IEnumerable. AuthorCategories will have to be pulled from the Database hence my question is:

Which way is the correct way of binding the dropdown with the categories;

1: Have the controller action to populate the data and pass the viewmodel to the view

2: Have the relevant property in the ViewModel getter access db and return a list such as:

```
   public List<AuthorCategory> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            using (DAL.AdminDbContext db = new DAL.AdminDbContext())
            {
                return new List<AuthorCategory>(db.AuthorCategories.ToList());
            }
        }
    }
```

3: Directly access the db from the View

4: ViewBag / ViewData?

5: Use AutoMapper?

How this is generally handled? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Always best to use a view model - i.e. it would contain 2 properties associated with the dropdownlist - `int SelectedCategory` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList` and in the controller initialize your view model and set `model.CategoryList = new SelectList(db.AuthorCategories, "ID", "Name");` and in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, Model.CategoryList)`

Comment: This is not a correct ansewer, but just my personal preference. 1) I  personally prefer approach 1. 2) I do not like to mix data access inside my view model. 3) I do not like my view know about data access. 4) I use [strongly typed view models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877601/binding-a-generic-list-to-a-dropdownlistfor-in-mvc3/12877767#12877767) instead of ViewBag. 5) I sometimes use Automapper, but it is not necessary to use it all the time.

Comment: Approach 2 is bad - a view model should never have access to the database (impossible to unit test). Ditto for 3. Approach 4 is OK but not strongly typed. And `AutoMapper` really has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using your `ViewModel` as a dummy data transfer object, option#2 is excluded. The role of `ViewModel` is to transfer data needed for the `View`. Apart it is good to have `Model` that is mapped to you database table. So here comes Automapper as it simplifies getting `ViewModel` out of `Model` and vice versa. Controller retrieves data from DB into `Model` and `ViewModel` is populated say with Automapper.

Option #3 of directly accessing the db from the View is not a good idea. Such code will be hard to debug and test. No separation of concerns.

Option #4 of using `ViewBag`/`ViewData` for such purposes is not a good one. There are a lot of mechanisms in razor view engine that rely on `@Model` present in View.